# Cognos 11 Content Store Import Issue

Tags: import, scheduled-tasks, reporting, cognos, cognos-11

The company I work for is switching from Cognos 11.0.7 to 11.2.3

I did an export of the content store from 11.0.7 and imported it into 11.2.3. All the reports and schedules were brought over. However, all the email recipients on the schedules are gone. Well, all the recipients added using the Cognos user directory are gone. Any emails that were manually entered are still there. I've been trying to find a way to repopulate all those recipients without having to manually go through each of our reports. We have over 300 active reports. But so far I haven't been successful.

I've done a couple test export/imports. I always check the option to "Include schedules". I also tried it with and without the option "Include distribution list and contacts" checked as well. I've tried it with reports I own and ones I don't. The last test I did was on a report I owned. I created a schedule to email to me, a second user, and an out of company email. Only my email and the out of company email remained. I believe this is because I was the owner and the out of company email was manually entered. The second user was added using the directory.

Is this just a bug that needs addressed by IBM, or is there something I can do now. Otherwise I'm doomed to manually update over 300 reports.

Comment: 300 reports, or 300 reports that have schedules?  Either way, that would be heaven.  I have about 20,000 reports.  In 11.1.7FP6 I've seen problems on some reports regarding schedules with emails configured using the directory namespace, so it may be a bug or a configuration flaw based on new requirements in the more recent version.  I was able to work around it easily, so I didn't spend any time investigating.  I couldn't reproduce the problem in the last few minutes based on a new report.

Comment: 20,000?! Damn. I feel better about my situation now. I spent most of my day yesterday manually fixing each schedule. I'm very close to being done. Would be nice to fins a quick fix solution, but I'm not holding out hope.